# 2 vertical css sprite images but different result

Tags: css, css-sprites

I created new sprite image using Instant Sprite, sprite_main.png and replaced old sprite image created by SpritMe, spriteme1.png.

I just changed image path and used given background positions  only but the result is disappointing with sprite_main.png. I don't understand what happen but is that because I added another 20+ icons to the sprite image?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/6TaQt/40/

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand the question. What do you try to do exactly, could you provide some finish image of what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background positions result is disappointing with **sprite_main.png** because sprite_main.png's height are different with (higher than) spriteme1.png's height and have defferent position for each icons between both images. So, you must re-calculate top background position.

Here my revision background position for sprite_main.png : http://fiddle.jshell.net/Vrf7g/

Comment: Thanks for your info. It seems that my coordinates are wrong. I regenerated them with Instant Sprite and got it right.